# thread safety for objects stored in the shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a `boost::shared_ptr<Map>`, and this map is being modified by multiple threads, do i need to use explicit mutex or just the fact that threads are modifying the map through shared pointer, i will get some sort of implicit thread safety?

Comment: No. `shared_ptr` absolutely does not do anything for thread safety. All it does is provide reference-counting semantics around a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no". The thread safety that `shared_ptr` provides is only for the pointer itself. It doesn't do anything to protect the object itself. Once you get a pointer to the underlying object out of the `shared_ptr` structure, no more magic happens for you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I always access objects via indirection to shared_ptr and not through the raw pointer. Would that offer thread safety ?

Comment: @Jimm: No. All the shared_ptr does is give you the pointer to the object. Nothing would stop one thread from modifying the object through that pointer while another was reading it. The shared_ptr's thread safety protects the system of shared pointers only, not the underlying object. (For example, it ensures sanity if two threads throw away their smart pointers to the same object at the same time or if one thread gets a regular pointer from a smart pointer at the same time another thread throws away a smart pointer to the same object and so on.)

Answer (score 2):

[Did you even look at the docs?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety)

> shared_ptr objects offer the same level of thread safety as built-in
>   types. A shared_ptr instance can be "read" (accessed using only const
>   operations) simultaneously by multiple threads. Different shared_ptr
>   instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such
>   as operator= or reset) simultaneosly by multiple threads (even when
>   these instances are copies, and share the same reference count
>   underneath.)
>
> **Any other simultaneous accesses result in undefined behavior.**

Edit: It looks like you're asking about the object pointed to, not the pointer itself. There are no thread safety gaurentees at all in that case. Why would there be?

Comment: If there is any possibility that the pointer you're reading is changing, then it is not safe to read it, much less than a regular pointer.  A regular pointer is one word, a shared pointer is a pointer to the object and a separate pointer to the count.  So reading from it is not inherently atomic on any architecture.  Therefor one problem is that you could read a value and a counter that don't match... Another problem is that if the shared pointer changes, it's possible that the object will be deleted in another thread part way through reading it.  The increment to the ref-count could corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` has the same level of thread safety as built-in types.

You can perform read (const) operations from multiple threads simultaneously.

You can also perform write operations (i.e. use mutable operations such as `operator=` or `reset`) on different `shared_ptr` instances simultaneosly from multiple threads. This includes the case when these instances share the same reference count (because `shared_ptr` provides atomic increment/decrement for the ref counter).

If you need any other type of access, you will need to synchronize it or otherwise you'll get undefined behavior.